# Name or service not known (api.sendgrid.com:443)

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, dns, sendgrid

I keep on getting this strange exception every now and then on a production server and I have zero clue as to why it keeps happening. I've tried contacting the provider with no luck and SendGrid.

It is an ASP.NET Core Web API application on .NET 7.0 running Dockerized on Rocky Linux 8 (`4.18.0-477.15.1.el8_8.x86_64`)

SendGrid .NET package is at version 9.28.1

Here is the full stack trace:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Name or service not known (api.sendgrid.com:443)
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|281_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.HttpConnectionWaiter`1.WaitForConnectionAsync(Boolean async, CancellationToken requestCancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>g__Core|5_0(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Sentry.SentryMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>g__Core|5_0(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at SendGrid.BaseClient.MakeRequest(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at SendGrid.BaseClient.RequestAsync(Method method, String requestBody, String queryParams, String urlPath, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at SendGrid.BaseClient.SendEmailAsync(SendGridMessage msg, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Notifications.Utils.Mailer.SendMailAsync(SendGridMessage msg) in /src/Notifications/Utils/Mailer.cs:line 17
   at Notifications.MailNotificationService.SendLoginVerificationAsync(User user, String ipAddress, String token) in /src/Notifications/MailNotificationService.cs:line 322
   at Authentication.Services.AuthenticationService.LoginAsync(String email, String password, String ipAddress, String code) in /src/Authentication/Services/AuthenticationService.cs:line 144
   at Api.Controllers.AuthController.AuthenticateUserAsync(LoginUserForm userForm, CancellationToken token) in /src/Api/Controllers/AuthController.cs:line 140
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Sentry.AspNetCore.SentryTracingMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
   at Sentry.AspNetCore.SentryTracingMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
   at Authentication.Middleware.ApiKeyVerificationMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next) in /src/Authentication/Middleware/ApiKeyVerification.cs:line 58
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<<UseMiddlewareInterface>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at AspNetCoreRateLimit.RateLimitMiddleware`1.Invoke(HttpContext context) in C:\Users\User\Documents\Github\AspNetCoreRateLimit\src\AspNetCoreRateLimit\Middleware\RateLimitMiddleware.cs:line 125
   at Sentry.AspNetCore.SentryMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
   at Sentry.AspNetCore.SentryMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<<UseMiddlewareInterface>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

I initially thought that the DNS servers on the host was the issue, it was using the providers DNS servers, so I switched them to Cloudflares DNS servers with no luck.

I then tried Googles DNS servers and that also did not help. Finally, I installed a system resolver (systemd-resolved) in the hopes that it would successfully resolve it at one point, cache the result and then we would be smooth sailing - this did not help either.

At this point I have no clue what to do and I really need some help with the problem.